# loadStreamableURLForFile() in Dropbox iOS SDK does not return anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

i'm trying to get a streamable link URL from an mp3 stored in my Dropbox for an app i'm developing. I use the function `loadStreamableURLForFile()` but it does not return anything, by the time it's of type `void`. 
So how am i supposed to get that streamable URL back?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Dropbox iOS Core SDK, the result of asynchronous calls like this get delivered via a delegate. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios and the use of `uploadedFile` and `uploadFileFailedWithError` in particular to understand the delegate pattern.

You should implement these methods (from `DBRestClient.h`) to receive the link:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)restClient loadedSharableLink:(NSString*)link 
forFile:(NSString*)path;
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)restClient loadSharableLinkFailedWithError:(NSError*)error;
```